# Double tap to zoom Windows Phone

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, zooming

I've a little problem with double tap to zoom, when I tap twice the image enlarge but I can see only half image and I can't move image to see other half of image. How can I for see all image?

The code is:

[XAML]

```
<!--LayoutRoot è la griglia radice in cui viene inserito tutto il contenuto della pagina-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF0A5BC4">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--ContentPanel - inserire ulteriore contenuto qui-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel Margin="-12,10,-11,98" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image x:Name="immagine_Name"  Margin="1,1,1,1" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="GestureListener_PinchStarted"
                                                                     PinchDelta="GestureListener_PinchDelta"
                                                                     DoubleTap="GestureListener_DoubleTap"/>
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Background="#FF094AB2" Margin="-12,675,-11,0">

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[C#]

```
private void GestureListener_DoubleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (transform.ScaleX == 1 && transform.ScaleY == 1) //The scale is currently 1, enlarge
    {
        transform.ScaleX = 1.5;
        transform.ScaleY = 1.5;
    }
    else
    { //Its bigger, reset to 1.
        transform.ScaleX = 1;
        transform.ScaleY = 1;
    }
}
```

This is the image to normal size:
http://i.imgur.com/vlUlbes.jpg

And this is the image after double tap, that I can't move for see the rest of image:
http://i.imgur.com/AZwsccq.jpg

Thank you for all who help me.

Comment: Try to get rid of the stackpanels.. use Rows/Columns instead

Comment: I've tried with rows/columns but, I still have the problem that I see half of the image. I need to put drag event in the gesture?

Comment: In the parent grid, you have set  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>, try to make that  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

Comment: Place your Image tag inside ScrollViewer and it will work.